# Is it possible to use the Azure Integration Runtime for onpremise data sources?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-data-factory

In most cases it is always the installation of a self-hosted integration runtime in the onpremise network. Or on another host machine (e.g. vm or even vm in the cloud) that can reach the onpremise data source (network settings, firewall rules). I am curious if it is possible to use the Azure integration runtime (for the managed service experience) to connect to the onpremise data sources. Is it possible if I set up a site-to-site with the azure vnet? Or express route? Do i have to expose the endpoints of the onpremise datasource? And how can the azure integration runtime can connect to it it is not in a vnet?

I am not strong in networking but i read all the documentation. I just cannot get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use Azure Integration Runtime for on-premise data sources because

By [enabling Managed Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-data-factory-managed-virtual-network/), Azure Integration Runtime supports connecting to data stores using **private link service** in a private network environment. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#azure-ir-network-environment).

By using a private link, you can connect to various platforms as a service (PaaS) deployments in Azure via a private endpoint. With a private endpoint, you can connect to PaaS via a private IP address within a specific virtual network and subnet.

By setting up an Internet Protocol security (IPsec) VPN (site-to-site) connection or an Azure ExpressRoute (private peering) connection, you can connect an on-premises network to your Azure virtual network.

Also, there is a similar STARTED feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/37105363-data-factory-should-be-able-to-use-vnet-without-re) for more reference.

Comment: thank you for the reply. How does it differ from a vnet that I create from the azure portal to a managed vnet by adf? Can I interact with it or is it not visible for me (adf managed vnet)?

Comment: You don't need to create the VNet for it and the IR managed VNet is created by Azure when you enable Managed Virtual Network IR. You just need to create Managed private endpoints for your PaaS. Azure Data Factory manages these private endpoints on your behalf.